# Xamarin form: show image using svg plugin

Tags: xamarin, svg

I have installed Xam.Plugins.Forms.Svg.

I tried to show an svg image in my @drawable android folder, without success. 
Anyone could gime me an example on how use a svg image?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/) nugget supports SVG Under the hood

- SVG
- WebP
- GIF

[image]

Comment: tx. how use it in xaml file?